# How to solve $t$ in $x = t - \sin{(t)}$

Tags: trigonometry, transcendental-equations

The question pretty much says it.

I need to solve $t$ in this equation:
$$ x = t - \sin{(t)} $$
Either I've forgotten how to do it, or I am just blind, etc. Anyway, I'm completely stuck at this.

Actually, I need to solve a vector:

$$(\; x \; , \; y \;) = (\; t - \sin{(t)} \; , \; 1 - \cos{(t)} \;)$$

Inverse of $y$ is trivial: $t = \cos^{-1}{(1 - y)}$. But that doesn't help me much further on.

Comment: You're not going to get a nice analytic solution.

Comment: You have not forgotten how to do it, nor are you blind. As far as I know, there is no way to invert $t-\sin t$ with (a finite number of) elementary functions. Instead (for your vector problem) you should use the $y$ coordinate to find $t$ up to a factor of $2\pi$, and then find this factor of $2\pi$ involving the $x$ coordinate. In your homework do $x$ and $y$ have particular values?

Comment: @anon no, they don't. $t$ is limited: $t \in [0,2 \pi]$, other than that, I should find the length of the line in this interval.

Comment: If you need to find the length of the curve, you do not need to solve for $t$.

Comment: If you are trying to find the area under an arch of the cycloid, or the arclength of part of the cycloid, the parametric equation is nice to work with directly.

Comment: The assignment just says, that I should find the length of it, doesn't say a thing about area.

Comment: Side remark:
This equation appears in study of the two-body problem as "Kepler's
equation", $\omega t = \psi - e \sin \psi$. Quoting from Goldstein's
"Classical mechanics", at the end of Section 3-8:
"The solution of the transcendental Kepler's equation to give the
value of $\psi$ corresponding to a given time is a problem that has
attracted the attention of many famous mathematicians ever since
Kepler posed the question early in the seventeenth century. [...]

Comment: (cont.)
Indeed, it can be claimed that the practical need to solve Kepler's
equation to accuracies of a second of arc over the whole range of
eccentricity fathered many of the developments in numerical
mathematics in the eighteenth and nineteenth centuries. A few of the
more than 100 methods of solution developed in the pre-computer era
are considered in the exercises to this chapter."

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053472/how-to-solve-keplers-equation-m-e-varepsilon-sin-e-for-e/4732665#4732665

Answer (score 5):

The length of the curve is the following:

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2}dt \\ 
=\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{(1-\cos t)^2 + (\sin t)^2}dt \\
=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1-2\cos t + \cos^2 t + \sin^2 t}dt \\
=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2-2\cos t}dt \\
=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-\cos t}dt. 
$$

Now recall one of the half-angle formulas: $\sin^2 u = \dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}\cos (2u)$. Plug in $t = 2u$ to obtain 
$$
\sin^2 \left(\frac{t}{2}\right) = \dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}\cos (t), 
$$
which is the same as 
$$
2 \sin^2 \left(\frac{t}{2}\right) =  1- \cos (t). 
$$

Returning back to our integral and making appropriate substitutions, we obtain 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2 \sin^2\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)}dt \\
= \int_0^{2\pi} 2 \sin \left( \dfrac{t}{2}\right) dt\\
= 2\int_0^{2\pi}\sin\left( \frac{t}{2}\right) dt. \\
$$

Finally, we finish by making a substitution: let $v = t/2$.  Then $dv = dt/2$. This is called a $u$-substitution but in order to avoid confusion, I'm using the letter $v$ instead.

Thus, we conclude

$$
2 \int_0^{\pi}\sin v (2dv) \\
= 4 \int_0^{\pi} \sin v dv \\ 
= -4 \cos v |_0^{\pi} \\ 
 = -4(-1-1) = -4 (-2) = 8. 
$$

Comment: Hint: $\cos(t) = \cos(2 t/2) = 1 - 2 \sin^2(t/2)$

Comment: Yes, thank you. Summer has obviously begun and I'm a bit rusty...

Answer (score 2):

To solve for t you would read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_equation. It is related to the Kepler equation. It can be done as a series, which may converge fast depending on the values.