# Solving Kepler's Equation

Tags: conic-sections, simulation, transcendental-equations

I've been working on simulating orbits. I've found that, when solving Kepler's equation, $M = E - \varepsilon\sin{E}$, I'm unsure about the solution to use. For a true anomaly $< \pi$, using the first solution is correct, but for angles larger than that the second solution must be used. Is this a pattern that repeats indefinitely? I'm having trouble consistently being able to identify the solution I should use. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't know anything about your specific question, but in case you don't know of it, Peter Colwell published a historical survey book on Kepler's equation in 1993 -- [**Solving Kepler's Equation over Three Centuries**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0943396409).

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053472/how-to-solve-keplers-equation-m-e-varepsilon-sin-e-for-e/4732665#4732665