# Find the inverse of $f(x) = 3x + \sin(\pi x)$

Tags: inverse-function

I understand that to find the inverse you switch the $x$ and $y$ then solve for $y$.
However, in this case you end up with $x=3y + \sin(\pi y)$. I know that the inverse exists and is a function since the $f$ is monotonic for all $x$.
Is there any way for me to isolate the $y$ and solve for the inverse?

Comment: The function $f$ is not one-to-one on $\mathbb{R}$ and hence not invertible on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The function is not monotonic. It decreases on very small intervals. I think the function you're looking for is $f(x) = πx + \sin(πx)$

Comment: If you had said f(x) = 3x + sin (x) you would have had a more interesting question.  As it is, we can say that f(x) is not injective (1-1) and so an inverse does not exist, and weasel our way out of answering the question.  But, even if you changed the function so that it was 1-1, the answer is unsatisfying.  The inverse  cannot be expressed as elementary functions.

Comment: is it really not one to one? when graphed, it appears so.

Comment: it is deceasing around odd integers, and increasing nearly everywhere else.

Comment: $f(0.9)=3.009...$ while $f(1)=3$ and $f(1.2)=3.01...$.

Comment: It decreases whenever $\cos(πx) < -\frac3π$, which is not often, but it does happen. Note that cos can go down to -1.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks for the help guys

Comment: Anyway, assuming $f(x) = πx + \sin(πx)$, the inverse exists, but can't be written out as an elementary function. We can give you a series solution for it, but I'm not sure you'd find that useful.

Comment: This is Kepler’s equation which has  known series solutions

Answer (score 0):

$$3x+\sin(\pi x)=y$$
$x\to\frac{t}{\pi}$:
$$\frac{3}{\pi}t+\sin(t)=y$$
$$t+\frac{1}{3}\pi\sin(t)=\frac{1}{3}\pi y$$

This is[Kepler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation).

see [How to solve Kepler's equation $M=E-\varepsilon \sin E$ for $E$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053472/how-to-solve-keplers-equation-m-e-varepsilon-sin-e-for-e/4732665#4732665)