# $x = a(\theta - \sin\theta)$, express $θ$ in terms of $x$

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

I've been battling with parametric equations recently and one of the situations I came across was a system of parametric equations that graph the cycloid of circle with radius $a$, which looks as follows:

$y=a(1-\cos\theta)$, $x=a(\theta-\sin\theta)$

Now I'm aware that it's possible to remove the parameter in this system (the parameter being either *a* or $\theta$), but is it possible to remove both? And also, when expressing $\theta$ in terms of *x*, is this process correct:

$\frac{x}{a}=\theta-\sin\theta$

$\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a}) = 2\theta$

$\frac{\sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})}{2}=\theta$

Comment: $$\cos\theta=?$$

Comment: In this instance, $cos\theta$ has no defined value as $\theta$ is the parameter variable, meaning $\theta$ can be anywhere between 0 and 89, and the result can be anywhere between 0 and 0.99999... @lab bhattacharjee

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation on
Kepler's equation
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation)
which can not be solved algebraically.

It can only be solved numerically.

However,
by using the power series
for $\sin$,
you could write
$y
=a\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
=ax\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(x^2)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}
$
and invert the
resulting power series
to as many terms as you want.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053472/how-to-solve-keplers-equation-m-e-varepsilon-sin-e-for-e/4732665#4732665