# Express $t$ through $a$ in $t-\sin(t)=a$.

Tags: trigonometry

Can I express $t$ throw $a$ in this expression?

$t-\sin(t)=a$

---

I don't know, whom should i tick. Thank you all.

I used half dividing method to fing $t$ in my task.

Comment: I think he means expressing $t$ solely through $a$, i.e. $t=f(a)$.

Comment: You can do it, but this is impossible in terms of elementary functions. In oter words, there is no formula for it.

Comment: @Crostul ok, so how can $t$ be expressed through $a$ using non-elementary functions?

Comment: I think it is unlikely that there is a closed form method to solve $t - \sin t = a$ for $t$ in terms of $a$.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053472/how-to-solve-keplers-equation-m-e-varepsilon-sin-e-for-e

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia article [Kepler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) gives the equation as

> $$ M = E - e\sin E $$

where we want to find $\,E\,$ given $\,M\,$ and $\,e.\,$
In your equation $\,e=1.\,$ The Wikipedia article states:

> Kepler's equation is a transcendental equation because sine is a transcendental function, meaning it cannot be solved for E algebraically. Numerical analysis and series expansions are generally required to evaluate E.

Answer (score 2):

As Yves Daoust answered, the simplest is Newton method.

If $a$ is small, you could use the usual series expansion of $\sin(t)$ and use series reversion to get
$$t=x+\frac{x^3}{60}+\frac{x^5}{1400}+\frac{x^7}{25200}+\cdots \qquad \text{where} \qquad x=\sqrt[3]{6a}$$

Answer (score 1):

in attempting to define an inverse function we must first choose a suitable domain of definition.

let $f(t) = t - \sin t$. if you wish to view $f$ as a real-valued function of a real variable then we have $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. clearly $f$ has derivatives of all orders. the first derivative is $f'(t) = 1 - \cos t$ which is zero for $t \in \{2\pi n|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

this shows $f$ is $1-1$, and monotonic increasing. so $f$ has a continuous inverse $g$ defined on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$, but to define $f$ a diffeomorphism, the zero-set of $f'$ must be excluded from the domain of definition.

if you keep those considerations in mind (which rule out the simpler Maclaurin expansion in this case), you can apply the  [Lagrange inversion theorem, also known as the Lagrange–Bürmann formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed-form solution to the equation

$$a=t-\sin t$$

and a numerical solution is in order.

The function is invertible, it is odd, repeating modulo $2\pi$, and it suffices to solve for $[0,\pi)$.

A good approach will be with Newton's iterations,

$$t_{n+1}=t_n-\frac{t_n-\sin t_n-a}{1-\cos t_n}$$

with the initial value $t_0=a.$

Anyway, for small $a$ the denominator is tiny (near horizontal tangent), and it can be safer to invert the Taylor development

$$a\approx \frac{t^3}6$$ or $$t\approx\sqrt[3]{6a}.$$

---

In the general case, a better initialization is the empirical

$$t=\sqrt[3]{\pi^2t}.$$