# How would you approximate the inverse of $y=\cos x+x$ or similar functions.

Tags: trigonometry

The function $y=\cos x+x$ passes the horizontal lines test, so it should have an inverse. But a quick Google search tells you that while such a function does exist it cannot be defined in elementary terms.

Is it possible to approximate an inverse function? Is doing so ever practical?

Comment: If you only need an inverse on a particular interval,  you could generate a polynomial function describing the inverse. There is no closed form unfortunately

Comment: Approximating is always possible. But your question is too vague to admit of an answer. Exactly what kind of approximation are you looking for?

Comment: Here's a question about a (rather famous) very similar function: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053472/how-to-solve-keplers-equation-m-e-varepsilon-sin-e-for-e

Answer (score 0):

You can use Numerical Analysis to invert by finding the solutions of $y = x + \cos x$ using [Bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) or [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Another approach is when you need an approximation locally, fit a polynomial there or something like a spline.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods like [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), [secant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method), [Muller's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muller%27s_method), Newton's method, [false position method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regula_falsi).

as @gt6989b mentioned if you need an approximation locally then you can use some polynomial interpolations like polynomial interpolation in the [Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) form or in the Newton form.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your example $f(x):=x+\cos x$ you can make use of the periodicity of $\cos$. Note that
$$f(x+2\pi)=f(x)+2\pi\qquad(-\infty<x<\infty)\ .\tag{1}$$
Assume that you have worked out a decent approximation $g$ of $f^{-1}$ in the interval $[f(0),2\pi]$: $$g:\quad \bigl[f(0),f(2\pi)]\to[0,2\pi],\quad y\mapsto g(y)\ ,$$  say a polynomial in $y$. This means that
$$g: \quad[1,2\pi +1]\to[0, 2\pi]\ ,$$
and
$$g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\approx x\qquad(0\leq x\leq 2\pi)\ .$$ You are satisfied with the precision; in particular $g\bigl(1\bigr)=0$ and $g(2\pi+1)=2\pi$.

For an arbitrary $y\in{\mathbb R}$ let $k_y:=\bigl\lfloor{y\over2\pi}\bigr\rfloor$. As a consequence of $(1)$ you then have the approximation
$$f^{-1}(y)\approx g(y-2\pi k_y)+2\pi k_y\qquad(-\infty<y<\infty)\ .$$