# Is there an exact solution to $x \sinh\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big) = a$?

Tags: functions, inverse-function, hyperbolic-functions, lambert-w, hyperbolic-equations

Is there an exact formula for solutions to the equation $x \sinh\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big) = a$ where $a,x \in \mathbb{R}^+$? And if not, why?

I tried to rearrange to apply Lambert W somewhere to no avail.

If it does exist, does it also exist for $x \sinh\Big(\frac{k}{x}\Big) = a$ where $k\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and is a known constant.

Wolfram only gives approximant solutions and no explanation, which is unfortunate.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=x+sinh%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2Cx%5D%5C%2841%29%3D2

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to express it in closed form unless you define some new special function or smth

Comment: Presumably, you mean an exact formula?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes that is what I meant.

Comment: Is $a$ a given and you really want to find an $x$ in terms of $a?$ Or are you really looking for any pair $(a,x)?$

Comment: @Max0815 Are there any existing non-elementary functions that would work?

Comment: Letting $y=1/x$ this becomes $\sinh y=ay,$ which might be easier. But I doubt there is a closed formula.

Comment: Starting with $\sinh y=ay.$ Using the standard formula, you get $e^y=ay+\sqrt{a^2y^2+1}.$ That will be a hard equation to get in a form to use the Lambert function.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think Ill just define a function $f(x)=x \sinh\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)$ and simply do $f^{-1}(x)$ then when writing. Ill just have to calculate values manually then. Thanks for the help tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x\sinh\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)=a\tag{1}$$
$$x\left(\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{k}{x}}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{k}{x}}\right)=a$$
$x\to\frac{k}{t}$:
$$\frac{1}{2}k(e^t)^2-ate^t-\frac{1}{2}k=0\tag{2}$$

We see, equation (2) is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($t,e^t$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $t$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

We see, for algebraic $a$ and $k$, equation (2) is an irreducible algebraic equation of $t$ and $e^t$ simultaneously. According to the theorems in [Lin 1983] and [Chow 1999], such kind of equations cannot have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) or explicit elementary numbers respectively. For algebraic $a$ and $k$, $x$ cannot be an elementary number except $0$ therefore. $0$ isn't a solution of equation (1).
Because $x$ is not an elementary number, we can prove that equation (1) cannot have partial inverses over non-discrete domains that are elementary functions.

We see, because equation (2) is a polynomial equation of $t$ and different powers of $e^t$ greater than $1$, the equation is not in a form for applying Lambert W or Generalized Lambert W.

$$x\sinh\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)=a\tag{1}$$
$$x=\frac{ki}{t}$$
$$ki\frac{\sinh(-it)}{t}=a$$
$$t-\frac{k}{a}\sin(t)=0$$

This is Kepler's equation. See e.g. [How to solve Kepler's equation $M=E-\varepsilon \sin E$ for $E$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053472/how-to-solve-keplers-equation-m-e-varepsilon-sin-e-for-e/4732665#4732665)

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ f(x)=x\sinh(\frac kx)=x(e^{\frac kx}-(e^{-\frac kx})/2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{k^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!x^{2n-2}}. $$
Clearly $f(x)$ is continuous and decreasing in $(0,\infty)$. Note
$$ \lim_{x\to0^+}=\infty, \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=k $$
and hence if $a>k$, the equation $f(x)=a$ has a unique solution; and $a\le k$, the equation has no solution.

Comment: Did you leave off dividing by 2 on purpose for the exponential form of sinh?

Comment: @K7PEH, you’re right. thanks

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do it to let $x=\frac 1y$ and face the problem of finding the zero of
$$f(y)=\sinh(y)-ay$$ If $a$ is "large" , a first estimate of the solution is given by
$$\frac 12 e^y=a y \quad \implies \quad y_0=-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2 a}\right)$$

For $a=2$, this would give $y_0=2.15329$ that is to say $x_0=0.464405$.

By Darboux theorem, $y_0$ is an under estimate of the solution if $a>3.151$.

Now, compute $y_1^{(n)}$, the first iterate of a Newton like method of order $n$. The formula is totally explicit.

For $a=2$, the results.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & y_1^{(n)} & \text{method} \\
 2 &  2.177565142 & \text{Newton} \\
 3 &  2.177317986 & \text{Halley} \\
 4 &  2.177318988 & \text{Householder} \\
 5 &  2.177318985 & \text{no name} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$