# How do I find the inverse function of $f(x)=\sin(x)+2x+1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

$$f(x) = \sin(x) + 2x + 1$$

After setting

$$x = \sin(y) + 2y +1$$

I don't know how to solve for $y$.

For context, the problem is asking to find $g'(x)$, knowing that $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$.

I thought maybe I could differentiate and find the inverse of $f'(x)$. Would that be $g'(x)$?

Thanks!

Comment: Various solutions for inverse [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053472/how-to-solve-keplers-equation-m-e-varepsilon-sin-e-for-e/4733405#4733405) or use [derivative of inverse function](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Calculus_(OpenStax)/03%3A_Derivatives/3.07%3A_Derivatives_of_Inverse_Functions)

Comment: I did the math formatting for you. Enclose equation lines in double dollars `$$...$$` and inline equations in single dollars `$...$`. Use built in functions like `\sin` and `\cos` for proper formatting, and do fractions with `\frac{a}{b}`. In general curly braces are used for grouping `{ .. }`, for example, to make a subscript use `x_{i+1}` that renders like $x_{i+1}$.

Comment: Do you know the inverse function theorem?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: First of there isn't an analytical function for the inverse of functions of this form $\sin(x) + a x$. 

What you are probably asked to do is [_implicit differentiation_](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/implicit-differentiation.html).

Comment: Thank you, @JohnAlexiou! Indeed, I believe this is an implicit differentiation problem. I'm just struggling to make the connection. If I differentiate implicitly and isolate _y'_, what do I have in relation to _g(x)_, aka the inverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of this exercise is the Inverse Function Theorem, which allows you to find the derivative of the inverse function at particular points under certain conditions (the link noted above in the comments explains this exactly so I will not state all that). It is particularly useful when you cannot find the inverse $g(x)$ explicitly using algebra as is the case here, and furthermore you should not generally expect to obtain $g'(x)$ as an explicit function.

A simpler example where we can find the inverse explicitly will help illustrate. Consider $f(x)=\frac 1{x-1}$. Then the inverse $g(x)$ is given by $g(x)=\frac 1x +1$. Obviously we have to exclude $x=1$ but this is fine: the IVT says we can operate in a small interval around any $x \ne 1$.

Since $g(f(x)) = x$, the chain rule gives that:

$g'(f(x))f'(x) =1$ or $g'(f(x)) = \frac 1{f'(x)}$.

You can already see that this generally will not allow you to find $g'(x)$ as an explicit function; however this formula does hold at individual points.

Back in the example, we have $f(2)=1$ and $g(1)=2$.

This tells us that $g'(1)$ should be $1/f'(2)$.  Since $f'(x) = \frac {-1}{(x-1)^{2}}$, $f'(2)=-1$.

In this case we can check: $g'(x) = -\frac 1{x^2}$ so $g'(1)=-1$.

Note that that $g'(x) \ne \frac 1{f'(x)}$ as functions which is a common misconception.

You should be able to apply this in your example now to get a formula for $g'(f(x))$.

Answer (score -3):

Inverse functions are found by doing all of the steps that were done to the original function in reverse order.  For example, to solve 2x + 3 = 11, think about how the function was constructed using PEMDAS.  X was multiplied by 2 (using a "getting dressed" analogy, "put on your socks") then 3 was added ("put on your shoes").  To solve it, subtract 3 ("take off your shoes") then divide by 2 ("take off your socks").  So if in the original function, the instructions are "take the sine, then add 2x, then add 1", to find the inverse, subtract 1, then subract 2x, then take the inverse sine/arcsine of this answer.  So it should be $f^{-1}(x) = \arcsin(x-1-2x) = \arcsin(-x-1)$.  I think.

Comment: This is incorrect since clearly $f(\arcsin(-x-1)) \neq x$.

Comment: This isn't right. "Add $2x$" isn't a simple operation once you've already applied $sin$ to to the original $x$, so you're not just applying these step by step. The entire function is more complicated and has an inverse that is much harder to describe. You can check by seeing that applying this function to original does not get you back where you started.

Comment: Originally $f(x) = \sin(x) + 2x + 1$, "subtract 1, then subract 2x, then take the inverse sine/arcsine" gives $$\arcsin (f(x)-1-2x) = x$$ or $$f^{-1}(x) = \arcsin(x-1-2f^{-1}(x))$$. How do you plan to remove the $x$ on the top left and the $f^{-1}(x)$ on the bottom right?

Comment: Your proposed $f^{-1}(x) = \arcsin(-x-1)$ is undefined for large $x$.

Comment: @Nate Have you considered deleting this "answer"?