# Attempting to Isolate X in the Following Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have been attempting to isolate $x$ in this equation and I thought I found a solution, but on graphing this, the output is undefined. I'm sure I've made an error in one of my steps but I have no clue about which one.
$$ax=\sin(bx+c)$$

These are the steps I've used during my calculations. $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all positive real numbers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
$$ax=\sin(bx)\cos(c)+\cos(bx)\sin(c)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}ax=\frac{d}{dx}\sin(bx)\cos(c)+\frac{d}{dx}\cos(bx)\sin(c)$$
$$a=b\cos(c)\cos(bx)-b\sin(c)\sin(bx)$$
$$\frac{a}{b}=\cos(c)\cos(bx)-\sin(c)\sin(bx)$$
$$\frac{a}{b}=\cos(c-bx)$$
$$\arccos(\frac{a}{b})=c-bx$$
$$bx=\arccos(\frac{a}{b})-c$$
$$x=\frac{\arccos(\frac{a}{b})-c}{b}$$

Comment: You cannot differentiate both sides as there the solutions $x$ are not an interval, but rather many distinct numbers/a number. For example,  $x-1=2$ has one distinct solution $x=3$, so differentiating both sides fails while $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ is true for $x$ on $[0,\infty)$, so both sides can be differentiated. You may use [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053472/how-to-solve-keplers-equation-m-e-varepsilon-sin-e-for-e) to solve your equation.

Comment: There is no closed form solution for $x$ in this equation.