# Need a basic formula for a slanted sine curve that keeps y as a dependent variable

Tags: trigonometry

I am a non-mathematician using applied math to try to solve a website monitoring problem with detecting deviations in traffic patterns on websites, and without getting into too much detail, need an equation of a sine curve that "slants".  I need to input $x$ (and other variables), and get $y$, so $y$ must be by itself on the left and no where else.

I tried this, but $y$ is not by itself so i cannot use:
$$y=\sin(x+\frac{y}{3})$$  I need to know $x$ before I can know $y$ as $y$ depends on $x$.  If there's a way to use this as a base but move the $y$ out of sine and over to the left, that might just answer this if it can absorb the other modifications below.

I tried this, but it's really just a sine curve within another, not a clean single line.  This matters because this equation will get heavily modified (below) and where they merge together will break it up, so it cannot be used: $$y=\sin(x+\frac{\sin(x)}{2})$$  By Unclean, it makes more sense when viewing it like this $y=sin(x+sin(x))$

If it helps, I made this and if I did not need it to slant, this is otherwise exactly what I need after all the modifications are implemented:

$$y=(max-min)*(\frac{1}{2}\sin(\frac{x-hour+6}{\frac{period}{2}}pi))+(\frac{max+min}{2})$$

$$y=(30-10)*(\frac{1}{2}\sin(\frac{x-3+6}{\frac{24}{2}}pi))+(\frac{30+10}{2})$$
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%3D%28%2830-%28%2810%29%29%29*%28%28sin%28%28%28x-%283%2B6%29%29%2F%2824%2F2%29%29*pi%29%29%2F2%29%29%2B%2830%2F2%29%2B%2810%2F2%29

It has variables for the min and max, the period in hours, aligning the lowest traffic to a specific hour.  It just doesn't slant to determine what hour is for the "max" traffic.  max traffic is never exactly $pi$ distance off (12 hours apart), it's usually like $\frac{3pi}{4}$ off (9 hours off).  The trough and crest of the website's traffic patterns are slightly off, so I need it to slant a varying amount depending on the constituent services that run the sites.

Ultimately this is going into a Prometheus Query, so there may be rare limitations with what the language allows me to use.  I don't think it will be an issue here, but calculus level things probably cannot be done.
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/

I'm not asking for someone to build the full formula, just hopefully provide a good base like in the first one that I can use knowing that it will have significant modifications like those shown above.  I am at about the end of my math abilities.

Thanks and I hope I am not asking for too much.  If I am, please provide what you can to help.

Much appreciated,

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "..... a sine curve that "slants" ...."  what do you mean by "slants" ??  Can you explain that in plain English ?

Comment: Tip: Write `$\sin$` for $\sin$.

Comment: You can [solve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053472/how-to-solve-keplers-equation-m-e-varepsilon-sin-e-for-e?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C77.3648) it by converting to a Kepler equation

Comment: Actually, it is much better if you let $x$ and $y$ be functions of a parameter $t$.  That is use parametric equations for $x$ and $y$ instead of writing $y$ explicitly in terms of $x$.

Comment: Thanks, i changed it to \sin.  By slant i mean like in the first 2 examples where the crest is not mid-way between the troughs.  I looked at the Kepler link, and I don't see the epsilon ε symbol in the Prometheus tool we're using, so it may not be possible.  I'll have to look up Kepler and find out what this is though.

Comment: @FigureOfCode $\epsilon$ is just a variable and can be renamed. You can rewrite your equation as $M=E-\epsilon \sin(E);M=x,E=x+\frac y3,\epsilon=\frac13$, solve for $E$, and then for $y$. However, there may be other methods too besides this one.

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash, I looked at what you wrote, but there's an x within sin and we are solving for x, which brings us back to the same issue with y being in both of places instead.  Sorry I don't know enough to know how this advances the solution.