# How to get inverse function of x-sin(ax)

Tags: functions, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

$f(x)=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{sin(200πx)}{400π}$

I'm not a mathematician. I'm making a heater which uses this formula to calculate the watt of given x. The problem is I need inverse of this function between (0 and 0.01) to use in PID algorithm. I couldn't get inverse of it so I asked  Wolfram Alpha which told me that it doesn't have a closed mathematical form. I know that functions can be represented as Taylor Series so is it possible to get inverse of this in terms of Taylor Series?

Comment: See [Kepler equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053472/)

Comment: The most practical way would be to implement a straightforward numerical scheme to compute the inverse function. Computationally it certainly is much simpler and efficient than any closed form formula, which probably does not exist.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention but I cant use computation since this function actually takes milliseconds as parameter so I cant use time consuming methods.